# Pronounce "e" like [ɛ] or [e]?

Tags: pronunciation, sound

I understand that in Italian the letter "e" can make two different vowel sounds:

- **[ɛ] like the e in bet**
- **[e] like the a in chaos**

Recently, I was caught off guard by an Italian song where the singer sang "vedo". Since I had learned to pronounce it as [vedo], I was surprised to hear it sung as [vɛdo] (which is correct?).

The rules I learned only pertained to particular conjugation endings like:

```
       Imperfect -ERE 

    rimanevo | rimanɛvamo
    —————————————————————
    rimanevi | rimanɛvate
    —————————————————————
    rimaneva | rimanevano


    We will eat: mangɛrɛmo
   We would eat: mangɛremmo
```

When encountering new words, are there any rules of thumb for figuring out which sound to use?

Comment: who knows :-) 
(I never managed to distinguish among the two e-s. I had to rote learn when to use the right accent...) The upside is that at least in northern Italy nobody really cares.

Comment: This is a very good question: I just want to remark that the same happens for [ɔ] and [o].

Comment: Where did you find such a thing as “rimanɛvamo”? No unstressed “e” is open in Italian...

Comment: @DaG - Am I correct in assuming that by an "open e" you intend [ɛ]? If so, I have been been pronouncing quite a few unstressed e's incorrectly for more than two years (so, I am happy that I asked this question). I wrote those examples in the way I have been pronouncing the e's.

Comment: @DaG so from your experience, the following from the above examples are incorrect: "rimanɛvamo", "rimanɛvate", "mangɛrɛmo", "mangɛremmo"?

Comment: Indeed, [ɛ] is often called “e aperta”, while [e] “e chiusa”. As @egreg explains in his answer, «unstressed *e* is always pronounced closed ([e] in IPA)». The only doubt can hold about stressed *e* s.

Comment: Asking yourself about accents/pronunciations without taking into account the speaker's origin is useless. The open/closed vowels change *a lot* between regions. But even accents change. I can't stand when people from Brescia say `mòllica` instead of `mollìca`. (the latter is correct according to [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mollica/) and the former is so well-known an error to be cited by [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mollica_res-57b46241-0026-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/) too)

Comment: Great discussion! Just try ordering a "venti" at Starbucks as I often do - they either fail to understand or ask do you mean a "vɛnti?"

Comment: Interesting, @Antonello, but that is a word borrowed in another language, not an Italian word anymore, so it has its own pronunciation (recorded as |ˈvɛnti| even in some dictionaries) and meaning (in Italy no one would understand it as a measure, in US units, for a serving of coffee).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The unstressed *e* is always pronounced closed ([e] in IPA). The classical example of a minimal pair is *pesca*, which is

- ['pɛsca] when it means “the peach”
- ['pesca] when it means ”fishing”

But regional pronunciation varies; in Northern Italy, both words usually have the closed *e*. In several local pronunciation schemes in Calabria there's no distinction between the two sounds.

How can one distinguish between the two sounds? By etymology. For instance, *neve* (snow) comes from Latin *nives*, so we can predict a closed vowel: ['neve]. On the contrary, *vento* (wind) comes from *ventus* and so an open vowel is used: ['vɛnto]. The numeral *venti* (twenty) originates from *viginti*, so the *e* is closed. Similarly, Latin's diphthong *ae* produces [ɛ].

However, it's fairly common to hear ['vento] for wind and ['vɛnti] for twenty and etymology can also be misleading. I'm not able to say ['neve], to be honest, and it's always ['nɛve] for me, because that's how it's pronounced in my region.

Comment: I guess Sicily would be a better example than Calabria for the "open e" (and for the "open o"): they really don't have the "closed" versions of both the sounds.

Comment: Even if I was born in Turin, I tend to pronounce [ɛ] even in the words who need [e] :-)

Comment: @mau It's the same in certain parts of Veneto, where the closed sound is almost inexistent.